# How to use threads to generate multiple sheets in a workbook - using axlsx gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, multithreading, axlsx

I use `axlsx` gem to generate an Excel workbook using the code below; I used multithreading expecting the Excel to be rendered faster:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

threads = []


wb.add_worksheet(name: "S1") do |sheet|
    sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines = false

threads << Thread.new{
    render :partial => "partial1_sheet1.xlsx.axlsx", :locals => {:wb => wb, :sheet => sheet}
}

threads << Thread.new{
    render :partial => "partial2_sheet1.xlsx.axlsx", :locals => {:wb => wb, :sheet => sheet}
}

threads << Thread.new{
    render :partial => "partial3_sheet1.xlsx.axlsx", :locals => {:wb => wb, :sheet => sheet}
}

end



threads << Thread.new{    
wb.add_worksheet(name: "S2") do |sheet|
    sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines = false

    render :partial => "partial_sheet2.xlsx.axlsx", :locals => {:wb => wb, :sheet => sheet}
end
}

threads << Thread.new{
wb.add_worksheet(name: "S3") do |sheet|
    sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines = false

    render :partial => "partial_sheet3.xlsx.axlsx", :locals => {:wb => wb, :sheet => sheet}
end
}

threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

I use 3 threads to render 3 partials inside sheet1 and one partial each for sheet2 & 3.

When I run this code, I get this error :

```
could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.169 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

I get this error in `partial1_sheet1` inside one of the `sheet.add_row` methods I use to add a row in the Excel.

What am I doing wrong here? What does this error mean really? And how can I work around it?

Comment: That is an ActiveRecord Timeout Error (nothing to do with axlsx) please ensure that your pool size in your database config is large enough to support the number of threads you are creating.

Comment: @engineersmnky - Thanks much for your comment - this was definitely helpful. I have one question though please - is there anything wrong with the way I have used threads in the code above? Because whether I use threads or not, the Excel rendering seems to take the same time. Can you please help?

Comment: (I am looking forward to using threads so that the total Excel rendering time would be reduced; but that does not seem to be happening with my code above. Why is that? Please help!)